# about dataset about drugs taken effects face changes

Tags: dataset, software-design, image-recognition, face, facial-identification

how I find the dataset about drugs taken by peoples, before and after changes of their faces. this is a new project that I tried to develop, very hard to find the relavant dataset.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you mean something like this:

https://www.rehabs.com/explore/faces-of-addiction/

https://wjla.com/news/crime/gallery/photos-before-and-after-faces-of-addiction-pictures-show-impact-of-drugs-on-men-women#photo-13

There are not so many entries but a few to get started.

The first one also includes what they were addicted to.

Hope that helps a bit :)

Comment: thank you for your help, my friend. i need data like that but it is better to have such data as a dataset. thanks again..